# Cannot disable locker service for recently created Sandbox - Summer 16'

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, locker-service

quick question - maybe somebody from SFDC team will be able to help me quicker than SFDC Support.

I've recently moved lightning components into newly refreshed Sandboxes, and I don't have an option there to disable "Locker Service" update. It used to be available under **Critical Updates**, but no longer is visible there.

As I can judge from Developer console log - the locker service is active.

I've already opened cases for two orgs where I see this problem: #14066524, #14066488

I'm not sure what's the reason - is it a new policy or just a bug? I know Lightning need some time to get more matured and stable, but these things that I observe recently are just really frustrating.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's policy. Existing orgs get the option to disable it grandfathered in for one more release. New ones require opening a case. It may be more difficult to disable after Winter '17, so don't treat it as a permanent workaround.

As noted [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2016/04/introducing-lockerservice-lightning-components.html)

> ### Availability
>
> LockerService will be made available starting Summer ‘16  in the following manner:
>
> - If the org is a brand-new Summer ‘16 org, or if the org has no Lightning components, the LockerService will be enabled automatically.
> - If the org has at least one Lightning component, the LockerService will be made available as a Critical Update and the Admin will decide.
>
> **Important**: LockerService will be auto-enabled for all orgs when Winter ‘17 is released in the October timeframe.

Also from the [Release Notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/rn_lightning_locker.htm):

> If you don't see this critical update in your org, LockerService has been automatically enabled and can’t be disabled. Automatic enablement occurs within 24 hours after the release.
>
> You can disable LockerService in a Developer Edition org created after the Summer ’16 release. We recommend that you test LockerService in a Developer Edition org to verify correct behavior of your components before enabling it in your production org.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, @Adrian, I opened a case (#14066524) asking to disable it, but they told me: "My apologies it cannot be disabled." Is it really true?

Comment: Wow, I would have thought they would still disable it. Guess not.

Comment: Yeah... that makes me really angry. Even though I like capabilities of Lightning, it's really frustrating - the way how all changes in the framework are done & communicated by Salesforce.